# Kendo Grid calls 'create' operation instead of 'update' after adding new record

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've setup a basic Kendo Grid and I'm using the DataSourceResult class from the PHP Wrapper library on the sever side.

I've come across a strange issue... if I `create` a new record and then edit it (without refreshing the page), the `create` operation is called again, rather than the `update` operation.

If the page is refreshed after adding the new record, the `update` operation is called correctly after making changes to the record.

I can confirm that the DataSourceResult class is returning the correct data after the `create` operation, including the `id` of the new record.

Any ideas why this is happening (and how to stop it)?
Thanks

Update: Here's the datasource code. The query string in the url is just to easily distinguish the requests in Chrome's console. The additional data passed with each request is used by `ajax.php` to distinguish the different actions requested.

```
data = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        create:  {
            url: '/ajax.php?r=gridCreate',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post',
            data: { request: 'grid', type: 'create' }
        },
        read:  {
            url: '/ajax.php?request=gridRead',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post',
            data: { request: 'grid', type: 'read' }
        },
        update: {
            url: '/ajax.php?r=gridUpdate',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post',
            data: { request: 'grid', type: 'update' }
        },
        destroy: {
            url: '/ajax.php?r=gridDestroy',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post',
            data: { request: 'grid', type: 'destroy' }
        },
        parameterMap: function(data, operation) {
            if (operation != "read"){
              data.expires = moment(data.expires).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
            }
            return data;
        }
    },
    schema: {
        data: 'data',
        total: 'total',
        model: {
            id: 'id',
            fields: {
                id: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                code: { type: 'string' },
                expires: { type: 'date' },
                enabled: { type: 'boolean', defaultValue: true }
            }
        }
    },
    pageSize: 30,
    serverPaging: true,
    serverSorting: true,
    serverFiltering: true 
});
```

Comment: Could I please see the DataSource initialisation code or any snippet that might be helpful?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. How are you calling the create and what does it return ? As part of debug, could you please add datasource.read() into your create complete event, to verify that your server side does what it should.

Comment: On the client side the grid is in 'popup' edit mode and I'm using a simple `toolbar: ["create"]` in the grid definition. The server side is an implementation of Kendo's own DataSourceResult.php which returnins a JSON object containing all the fields along with the ID of the new record. I'll give the `datasource.read()` a try and let you know what happens.

Comment: Hi,I have the same problem as you have. If you get any solution then please let me know how you have solved it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have also the same problem & I have tried this & it will work.

```
.Events(events => events.RequestEnd("onRequestEnd"))
```

And in this function use belowe:

```
function onRequestEnd(e) {
    var tmp = e.type;
    if (tmp == "create") {
        //RequestEnd event handler code
          alert("Created succesully");
        var dataSource = this;
        dataSource.read();
    }
    else if (tmp == "update") {
          alert("Updated succesully");
    }
}
```

Try to Use this code in onRequestEnd event of grid

```
var dataSource = this;
    dataSource.read();
```

Hope that it will help you.

Answer (score 9):

Best solution

> Set to update, create or delete different Call Action

From Telerik Support :

> I already replied to your question in the support thread that you
>   submitted on the same subject. For convenience I will paste my reply
>   on the forum as well.
>
> This problem occurs because your model does not have an ID. The model
>   ID is essential for editing functionality and should not be ommited -
>   each dataSource records should have unique ID, records with empty ID
>   field are considered as new and are submitted through the "create"
>   transport.

```
 schema: {
     model: {
         //id? model must have an unique ID field
         fields: {
             FirstName: { editable: false},
             DOB: { type: "date"},
             Created: {type: "date" },
             Updated: {type: "date" },
         }
     } },
```

> For more information on the subject, please check the following
>   resources:
>
> http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/model#methods-Model.define
>   http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/grid/request-for-support-on-editable-grid.aspx#228oGIheFkGD4v0SkV8Fzw

[MasterLink](http://www.telerik.com/forums/grid's-create-update-and-destroy-operations-are-calling-a-single-url-assigned-to-create-)

> I hope this information will help

Answer (score 0):

Pass the  auto-incremented id of the table when you call the `get_data()` method to display data into kendo grid, so that when you click on the delete button then `Deledata()` will call definitely.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another variation, in my case, I had specified a defaultValue on my key field:

```
        schema: $.extend(true, {}, kendo.data.transports["aspnetmvc-ajax"], {
            data: "Data",
            total: "Total",
            errors: "Errors",
            model: kendo.data.Model.define({
                id: "AchScheduleID",
                fields: {
                    AchScheduleID: { type: "number", editable: true, defaultValue: 2 },
                    LineOfBusinessID: { type: "number", editable: true },
```

Not sure what I was thinking  but it caused the same symptom.